# How do I get a list of corporations where corporation (ID) is included?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, recursive-cte

***IMPORTANT ... in my RL project, the ID's aren't INT, but GUID, so my data is NOT hierarchical!***

I have a table with companies and a table with links between companies.

I need to be able to retrieve a list of companies from a specific company ID.

Here's my test code...

```
CREATE TABLE ##corporations
(  
    CorporationID INT NOT NULL,  
    CorporationName NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);  

CREATE TABLE ##corporationLinks
(  
    FromCorporationID INT NOT NULL,  
    ToCorporationID INT NOT NULL
);  

INSERT INTO ##corporations (CorporationID, CorporationName) VALUES (1, 'Nike')
INSERT INTO ##corporations (CorporationID, CorporationName) VALUES (2, 'Cocal Cola')
INSERT INTO ##corporations (CorporationID, CorporationName) VALUES (3, 'Apple')
INSERT INTO ##corporations (CorporationID, CorporationName) VALUES (4, 'Google')
INSERT INTO ##corporations (CorporationID, CorporationName) VALUES (5, 'Amazon')
INSERT INTO ##corporations (CorporationID, CorporationName) VALUES (6, 'Samsung')

INSERT INTO ##corporationLinks (FromCorporationID, ToCorporationID) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT INTO ##corporationLinks (FromCorporationID, ToCorporationID) VALUES (2, 3)
INSERT INTO ##corporationLinks (FromCorporationID, ToCorporationID) VALUES (4, 5)
INSERT INTO ##corporationLinks (FromCorporationID, ToCorporationID) VALUES (4, 6)

SELECT * FROM ##corporationLinks WHERE FromCorporationID = 2 OR ToCorporationID = 2

/** 

Organisations (##corporationLinks) are...

Nike + Coca Cola + Apple + Marcy

and...

Google + Amazon + Samsung

**/

-- How do I eg get a list of companies where Coca Cola is in ... that is where FromCorporationID = 2 OR ToCorporationID = 2 ... result should be Nike, Coca Cola and Apple?
-- How do I eg get a list of companies where Samsung is in ... that is where FromCorporationID = 6 OR ToCorporationID = 6 ... result should be Google, Amazon Cola and Samsung?

DROP TABLE ##corporationLinks 
DROP TABLE ##corporations
```

UDPATE:

If I need to find corporations where Coca Cola is part of then I would do the fowlling...

SELECT * FROM ##corporationLinks WHERE FromCorporationID = 2 OR ToCorporationID = 2

Then I will get 2 results...

```
FromCorporationID   ToCorporationID
-----------------------------------
1                   2
2                   3
```

Here after I need to look into which corporations the result is part of...

```
SELECT * FROM ##corporationLinks WHERE FromCorporationID = 1 OR ToCorporationID = 1

SELECT * FROM ##corporationLinks WHERE FromCorporationID = 3 OR ToCorporationID = 3
```

Then I will get one more corporation (7):

```
FromCorporationID   ToCorporationID
-----------------------------------
3                   7
```

And then I need to dive into which corporations that is linked with 7...

```
SELECT * FROM ##corporationLinks WHERE FromCorporationID = 7 OR ToCorporationID = 7
```

And dive into that result too (guess it is called recursive). etc.

UPDATE 2:

I've updated my sample above to add one more company that should be returned if search is Coca Cola.

Expected result from the query (Coca Cola) above:

```
CorporationID:
--------------
2
1
3
7
```

Comment: Use a Recursive CTE query to query a hierarchical relationship.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear (I've updated my post) ... In my RL project I'm not using INT, but GUID ... and it is not hierarchical data.

Comment: So... you're asking how to write a trivial `SELECT` query?

Comment: Nope ... please see the update to my post.

Comment: What is your expected output in tabular format?

Comment: You've contradicted yourself - you said your data is not hierarchical (which has nothing to do with using GUIDs, btw) but then you say you need to recursively repeat your query.

Comment: @forpas .. I've updated my post with the result I would like.

Comment: @Dai .. I don't think you can call it hierarchical when there is no parrent?

Comment: Is there any possibility of a cycle in your data, e.g. `'Apple'` → `'Amazon'` → `'Google'` → `'Apple'` → ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a recursive `CTE`:

```
with 
  root as (select CorporationID id from companies where CorporationName = 'Coca Cola'),
  cte as (
    select 
      case when r.id = cl.FromCorporationID then cl.ToCorporationID else cl.FromCorporationID end id,
      case when r.id = cl.FromCorporationID then cl.FromCorporationID else cl.ToCorporationID end otherid      
    from corporationLinks cl inner join root r
    on r.id in (cl.FromCorporationID, cl.ToCorporationID)
    union all
    select 
      case when c.id = cl.FromCorporationID then cl.ToCorporationID else cl.FromCorporationID end id,
      case when c.id = cl.FromCorporationID then cl.FromCorporationID else cl.ToCorporationID end otherid            
    from corporationLinks cl inner join cte c
    on c.id in (cl.FromCorporationID, cl.ToCorporationID)
    and c.otherid not in (cl.FromCorporationID, cl.ToCorporationID)
  )
select id CorporationID from root
union all
select id from cte
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=b3236309b2c7ff3cda66478ea917ed48).
Results:

```
> | CorporationID |
> | ------------: |
> |             2 |
> |             1 |
> |             3 |
> |             7 |
```

Answer (score 0):

left join the ##companies,  include its CorporationID or you can include the companyname in the query then group by CorporationID you should be able to see which company it belongs to

Comment: I can't see that will work, for if I search for "Coca Cola", then how will "Marcy" be part of the result with your solution?

Comment: If you search for Coca Cola only then all results would be under Coca Cola, same goes to Marcy, if you want to see both or all, then select all corporations without filtering which company, i hope thats what you mean

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear enough. I don't need to search the ##corporations table ... I need to search the ##corporationLinks to find which corporations that is linked with eg "Coca Cola" .. and that will be 1, 2, 3 and 7.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a recursive CTE

```
WITH cte
AS
(
    SELECT l1.FromCorporationID,l1.ToCorporationID
    FROM ##corporationLinks l1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.FromCorporationID,l3.ToCorporationID
    FROM ##corporationLinks l3
    JOIN cte 
        ON cte.ToCorporationID = l3.FromCorporationID

)

SELECT cte.ToCorporationID--parent
FROM cte
WHERE cte.FromCorporationID =2
UNION
SELECT cte.FromCorporationID--child
FROM cte
WHERE cte.ToCorporationID =2
UNION
SELECT c.CorporationID--self
FROM ##corporations c
WHERE c.CorporationID = 2
```